# CMake: find wxWidgets built with MinGW/MSYS?

Tags: cmake, mingw, wxwidgets, msys

I compiled wxWidgets 2.8.12 using MinGW. To actually do the build I invoked the autotools build files distributed with wxWidgets through the MSYS shell, using an install prefix of H:\MinGW-libs.

The result of this is that I have a Unix style file tree containing my wxWidgets headers and libs (which are .a files, not .dll) with root directory H:\MinGW-libs.

My problem is that I can't get CMake to find the files. When I try to use the "configure" button in the CMake gui it finds other dependencies (namely boost, for which I had to specify BOOST_ROOT, but it does not find wxWidgets. I see that wxWidgets_ROOT_DIR is an available constant that I can set but none of the obvious choices

`H:\MinGW-libs` (my install prefix for wxWidgets)

`H:\MinGW-libs\lib`

`H:\MinGW-libs\include`

fix the error.

There is an [old post on the CMake mailing list](http://www.cmake.org/pipermail/cmake/2008-July/022624.html) about this issue but there isn't actually any information indicating how to fix it in this use case. The only hint I have is that there's a difference between looking for wxWidgets in "Unix style" file trees and "Windows style" file trees.

How can I get CMake to find wxWidgets installed in a Unix style file tree on Windows 7? Is there are way to get CMake to use wx-config? I ask this because from the MSYS command line using wx-config to get lib and header locations works just fine.

Comment: your libraries are not generated to `C:/wxWidgets/lib/gcc_lib` ?

Comment: Actually yes they are, but after building the libs I 'make install'ed them into H:\MinGW-libs. Why do you ask this?

Answer (score 3):

From `FindwxWidgets.cmake`:

```
if(WIN32 AND NOT CYGWIN AND NOT MSYS)
  set(wxWidgets_FIND_STYLE "win32")
else()
  if(UNIX OR MSYS)
    set(wxWidgets_FIND_STYLE "unix")
  endif()
endif()
```

So Unix-style tree is assumed for the "MSYS Makefiles" generator (`cmake -G "MSYS Makefiles"`) but not for the "MinGW Makefiles" generator.
Which one do you use?