# Cmake cannot find wxWidgets on Windows

Tags: cmake, wxwidgets

I have searched for this topic and found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61716701/how-do-i-use-wxwidgets-with-mingw-w64-and-clion) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18433305/cmake-find-wxwidgets-built-with-mingw-msys), but it only seems to either pertain to *building* wxWidgets or do not contain an answer to my question.

I have built the static libs für wxWidgets on Windows successfully, but I am now struggling to correctly include the libraries to my project using Cmake. This is my `CMakeLists.txt`:

```
set(PROJECT_NAME wxapp)
project(${PROJECT_NAME})
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 2.8)

set(SRC_LIST main.cpp app.cpp app.h frame.cpp frame.h)
add_executable(${PROJECT_NAME} WIN32 ${SRC_LIST})

find_package(wxWidgets REQUIRED net gl core base)
include(${wxWidgets_USE_FILE})
target_link_libraries(${PROJECT_NAME} ${wxWidgets_LIBRARIES})

set(wxWidgets_USE_LIBS ON)
set(wxWidgets_CONFIGURATION msw)
```

I have set the `WXWIN` path variable correctly. Yet, CMake throws an error with this configuration:

```
Could NOT find wxWidgets (missing: wxWidgets_LIBRARIES
wxWidgets_INCLUDE_DIRS net gl core base)
```

I have tried multiple suggestions, like using downloading prebuild dynamic libraries and adding them manually as suggested [here](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.0/module/FindwxWidgets.html), e.g.

```
set(wxWidgets_ROOT_DIR $ENV{WXWIN})
set(wxWidgets_LIBRARIES $ENV{WXWIN}/include)
set(wxWidgets_INCLUDE_DIR $ENV{WXWIN}/lib/vc14x_x64_dll)
include_directories(includes $ENV{WXWIN} $ENV{WXWIN}/include $ENV{WXWIN}/lib/vc14x_x64_dll)
link_directories($ENV{WXWIN} $ENV{WXWIN}/include $ENV{WXWIN}/lib/vc14x_x64_dll) # this seems to be a discouraged/deprecated method
```

but all to no avail.

Comment: "I have built the **static** libs for wxWidgets on Windows successfully" - But the name of `vc14x_x64_dll` directory suggests that you have `.dll` libraries, that is **dynamic** ones. Anywhere, what **exact value** you have assigned to `wxWidgets_ROOT_DIR` variable and what layout of files under that directory?

Comment: You need to set those variables before calling `find_package`.  Also, see the search path here: https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/command/find_package.html#search-procedure

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Did you try Googling the error message? When doing so, I found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/48945965/3987854) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41578736/3987854) question, which appear to have helpful suggestions. Did you try these?

Comment: @StephenNewell: Documentation for `find_package` describes search procedure only for `CONFIG` files. But message `Could NOT find wxWidgets (missing: ...)` implies that `MODULE` mode has been used, and corresponded "Find" script has been found by CMake. The search procedure implemented by this script is described in the script itself (and in the corresponded [doc page](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.0/module/FindwxWidgets.html)) and isn't standardized by `find_package`.

Comment: Yes, I have built the static libs, but have then followed one hint and downloaded the dynamic libs as well to eliminate the possibilities of building error. My wxWidgets_ROOT_DIR is my wxWidgets main directory, which contains the include and lib directory, currently located at D:\libs\wxWidgets

Comment: @squareskittles: I have found those and tried them both prior to asking this question. One of the links also refer to FindwxWidgets, which states to link the libs manually.

Comment: Hm, actually the script [FindwxWidgets.cmake](https://github.com/Kitware/CMake/blob/master/Modules/FindwxWidgets.cmake) (used by `find_package(wxWidgets)`) searches under directories specified both in `WXWIN` and `wxWidgets_ROOT_DIR` **environment** variables. So, having `WXWIN` environment variable should be sufficient for hint CMake about your wxWidgets installation. What is searched under this directory is `include/wx/wx.h` file. Do you have this file? What is **absolute path** to it on your machine? By knowing the absolute path we could suggest value of `WXWIN` variable which should work.

Comment: @user14264698, why do you want to use CMake? wxWidgets provides solutions to every compiler and most used IDEs on the market...

Comment: @Tsyvarev: Yes, I have this file under D:\libs\wxWidgets\include\wx\wx.h with my WXWIN set to D:\libs\wxWidgets. That path should work, right?

Comment: @Igor: I am using CLion and to my knowledge, wxWidgets should work without issues with CMake.

Comment: Yes, the path `D:\libs\wxWidgets` should work.. assuming you use the latest CMake version. But what actual CMake version do you use?

Comment: The CMake version is 3.17.3 and I am using CLion with MingW. Is it a problem that I used the user environment path variable and not the system environment path variable?

Comment: a `echo %WXWIN%` points to `D:\libs\wxWidgets` so the path should be readable for CMake

Comment: Have you used any of the CMake trace options to help debug the issue? You also have a few typos and are setting the wrong variables and are also not following the Sample usage in the 3.17.3 documentation that states `Note that for MinGW users the order of libs is important!` and `find_package(wxWidgets COMPONENTS gl core base OPTIONAL_COMPONENTS net)`

Comment: @fdk1342: could you elaborate on the typos and wrong variables?

Comment: From what I can tell, I am sticking to the sample usage. I am using `find package` before `include` and `target_link_libraries` which is in accordance with the instructions. I copied and pasted the `find_package(wxWidgets COMPONENTS gl core base OPTIONAL_COMPONENTS net)` also to no avail.

Comment: It looks like you are trying to override the variables that would have been set by the module, but using `$ENV{WXWIN}` without quoting or otherwise accounting for backslashes vs forward slashes.  The documentation does state that `wxWidgets_ROOT_DIR` and `wxWidgets_LIB_DIR` can be used to give the hint of where to find the items *before* calling `find_package`.  In this case you should still be using forward slashes as that is what CMake expects; properly quoting backslashes may work. Also making these kinds of changes will only work after clearing the cache.

Answer (score 3):

**WORKAROUND (at least it works for me):**

I changed the `find_package` command from the suggested statement:

`find_package(wxWidgets COMPONENTS gl core base OPTIONAL_COMPONENTS net)`

to

`find_package(wxWidgets 3.1 REQUIRED)`

A user in [this post](https://forums.wxwidgets.org/viewtopic.php?t=43591) had this included in his/her CMake file and out of deperation, I tried this and it actually worked. Seems like the configuration of CMake under certain unknown circumstances won't function correctly with the statement provided in the instructions. If I change the command to the new statement my static build as well as self- and precompiled dlls are flawlessly identifed by CMake.

I also cleared the CMake cache, inspired by [this post](https://forums.wxwidgets.org/viewtopic.php?f=19&t=46509). According to this post, there seems to be an issue with Windows and the CMake cache in some situations, but the reasons escape me. I could replicate the behaviour observed by the user there:

> Under Windows, you have to point to the installation directory, e.g.
>
> set(wxWidgets_ROOT_DIR "C:/wxWidgets-3.1.3") set(wxWidgets_LIB_DIR
> "C:/wxWidgets-3.1.3/lib/vc14x_x64_dll")
>
> But then the behavior is still strange. When i use CMake GUI (3.16,
> latest), behavior is like this
>
> 1. delete cache (just to be consistent)
> 2. press 'configure' button
>    --> fail: CMake Error at C:/Program Files/CMake/share/cmake-3.16/Modules/FindPackageHandleStandardArgs.cmake:146
>    (message): Could NOT find wxWidgets (missing: wxWidgets_LIBRARIES
>    wxWidgets_INCLUDE_DIRS core base qa adv net html gl propgrid richtext)
> 3. press 'configure' button again
>    --> success

I also have observed some inconsistent behaviour of CMake *within* the IDEs CLion and CodeBlocks when clearing the cache and reloading the project.

So, exactly how the cache clearing plays into the resolution of my issue, I don't know. But if I merely clear the cache, reload my project and leave the CMake instruction at `find_package(wxWidgets COMPONENTS gl core base OPTIONAL_COMPONENTS net)`, CMake won't find my installation despite the `WXWIN` path being set correctly.

If you know more about this, I am happy to be corrected.

Comment: Hi, I meat the same issue here, see discussion on msys2's github issue link here: [wxWidgets is not found from CMake when using Ninja in MSYS · Issue #10963 · msys2/MINGW-packages](https://github.com/msys2/MINGW-packages/issues/10963), the result message is quite strange, ` Could NOT find wxWidgets (missing: core base) (found suitable version "3.1.5", minimum required is "3.1")
`